# Completely uninstall ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I am attempting to uninstall Ubuntu. I purchased a copy of windows 7 and I need to completely wipe Ubuntu from my laptop. I did not dual install Ubuntu and windows when I started using Ubuntu, I simply wiped Windows from my hard drive. Can anyone help please!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just tell Windows to use the whole hard drive. Windows will format it and use it all up. Unless, of course, you'd like to move some data between the old Ubuntu and the new Windows. In that case best if you use an external disk or USB stick.